# How to hide two divs that must not be active at the same with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have two charts, one Emotion chart and one Polarity chart. I have two buttons, one for each chart. By clicking the first button, the first chart must be shown, and only that. When I click the second button, the first chart must be hidden and the second chart must be shown.

Also, I have a button that hides the entire chart that is active at the time.
Is it possible to do the hiding part with Bootstrap only?

I've added some event listeners when each button is clicked. You will find a minimal reproducible example in the link that follows:

```js
let isEmotionsButtonActivated = false;
let isPolarityButtonActivated = true;

const emotionsButton = document.getElementById("emotions");
const polarityButton = document.getElementById("polarity");

const emotionsChart = document.getElementById("multiCollapseExample1");
const polarityChart = document.getElementById("multiCollapseExample2");


polarityButton.classList.add("active");
polarityChart.classList.add("show");

emotionsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!isEmotionsButtonActivated) {
    isEmotionsButtonActivated = true;
    isPolarityButtonActivated = false;

    polarityChart.classList.remove("show");
    emotionsChart.classList.add("show");

    emotionsButton.classList.add("active");
    polarityButton.classList.remove("active");
  }
});

polarityButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!isPolarityButtonActivated) {
    isEmotionsButtonActivated = false;
    isPolarityButtonActivated = true;
    
    emotionsChart.classList.remove("show");
    polarityChart.classList.add("show");

    emotionsButton.classList.remove("active");
    polarityButton.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="emotions" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Emotions</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="polarity" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Polarity</button>
  
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Hide</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Emotions Chart Placeholder
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Polarity Chart Placeholder
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Hide button however hides the active chart and shows the hidden chart. I want to hide the active chart only. Is that possible with Bootstrap only and no JS?

Also, if I remove the `data-bs-target` from each button, the animation when I click "Emotions" or "Polarity" buttons does not exist. The hide process becomes instantly. Is that a normal behavior? I am new to Bootstrap, I thought that by removing the `data-bs-target`, the button should not know which element is the target for it to show.

Comment: Please include a [mre] here.

Comment: Questions shouldn't rely on external sources to be answered.

Comment: I've edited the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No custom JavaScript solution**

The question asks how to hide both Bootstrap Collapse components without using any custom JavaScript.

Yes, this is possible by wrapping both components in a another Collapses which is used to show or hide them.

The key to making the toggle work is to add the `.show` class to the first inner Collapse.  This causes Bootstrap to toggle between the two so that only one is shown. This allows us to remove the +20 lines of custom JavaScript in the original.

**Snippet**

```html
<p>
Uncheck the hide button and toggle between charts with radio buttons.
</p>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  
    <input type="radio" 
      id="btnradio1"
      class="btn-check" 
      name="btnradio"
      autocomplete="off"
      checked
      data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target=".multi-collapse">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">
    Emotions
    </label>

    <input type="radio" 
      class="btn-check" 
      name="btnradio" 
      id="btnradio2" 
      autocomplete="off" 
      data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target=".multi-collapse">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">
    Polarity
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" 
      class="btn-check" 
      id="check1" 
      autocomplete="off" 
      checked
      data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target="#exampleCollapse">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="check1">
    Hide
    </label>
    
</div>

<hr>

<div  id="exampleCollapse" class="collapse"> <!-- Added wrapper -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="multi-collapse collapse show">  <!-- Added .show -->
        <div class="card card-body">
          Emotions Chart Placeholder
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="multi-collapse collapse">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Polarity Chart Placeholder
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**UPDATE** - alternative solution

In a follow up question, OP asked how to programmatically sequence the the collapse components without breaking the built-in animation. The problem with the original code is that it toggles the `.show` class directly. This breaks the animation because Bootstrap applies a css transition and afterwards removes the `.show` class. And so if you toggle the .show class breaks both the animation and collapse events.

The easy workaround is to use Bootstrap's show/hide methods as shown in the following snippet.

**Snippet 2**

```js
let button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');

let collapse1 = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance('#collapseExample1');

let collapse2 = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance('#collapseExample2');

let index = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // logic to show the graphis is some
  // specific order

    index++;
  if (index > 3) index = 0;

  if (index === 0) {
    collapse1.hide();
    collapse2.hide();
  }
    else if (index === 1) {
    collapse1.show();
    collapse2.hide();
  }
    else if (index === 2) {
    collapse1.hide();
    collapse2.show();
  }
  else {
    collapse1.show();
    collapse2.show();
  }

});
```

```html
<button id="toggleButton" class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="button">
    Toggle
</button>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <h3>GRAPH 1</h3>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOiNx.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <h3>GRAPH 2</h3>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOiNx.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, the Hide button targets the added wrapper, to hide any content that is with the .show class at the time. That's very good! Thank you.
About the animation, if I remove the data-bs-target, the behavior is considered normal? When switching from Emotions to Polarity, or Hiding content, there is a smooth animation.

Comment: Partially, yes. Does the ```data-bs-target``` affect the animation if I remove it? Does it have to do anything with the animation at all?

Comment: Both solutions will help me to understand it better. Thank you, I will try them!

Comment: hello! Sorry for disturbing you again after you gave the solution. I've noticed that when clicking the first button, the content toggles, as it would, because both buttons have a `data-bs-target` of `.multi-collapse`. My desired behaviour is that I want to show the content B when I click the button B, and show the content A when I click the button A. Now I can click the button A and I can toggle between content A and B. I can achieve my desired behavior with the methods hide and show ? 

Thanks.

Comment: That's great!

I am curious, can it be done with the previous method that you showed?? Both the buttons have `data-bs-target` as `.multi-collapse` so each button can toggle both contents. If I change the target, from a common class to a specific id, the toggle stops, but now the second content does not get hidden when I click the first button. Each button has its own target, but neither can hide the other when clicked.

Comment: I mean, can it be done with the data attributes and only show the content when its button is clicked, like you did with the hide/show methods?? What you describe is what you have showed me before and what I've implemented. Buttons toggle on and off, but I need to show content A only when button A is clicked, not to toggle between content A and B.

Comment: I want to achieve the same result with the hide/show example that you provided, but without the hide/show methods. Instead, I want to use data attributes. 

In your example with the hide/show methods, I cannot press the `show B` button twice, it is only clicked once and showed the content once. Nothing happens when I click the "show B" button multiple times. When I click "show A" button, content B is hidden, content A shows, and vice versa. I want to achieve that, but with data attributes. Is it possible?

Comment: I do not want toggling behavior. I want two buttons, each button to show its content and not toggling between each other and I am curious If I can do it with data attributes.

Comment: Thank you. But now both charts are shown at the same time, and as I said in the previous comments, I do not want that. Maybe what I want is not possible with `data attributes`. Only hide/show methods can do that, apparently, just like your example https://jsfiddle.net/4b9f6krm